# Unable to execute a class extending Thread with main method in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

Unable to execute this in eclipse. Is there any particular reason for it? Does eclipse look for anything specific before enabling the execute option?
And what will be the result if the below code is executed? Is it "1"?

```
class A extends Thread {
    private int i;
    public void run(){i=1;}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(); a.run();System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}
```

Edit: Just playing around with inheritance and Threads. No specific Thread functionality is tested here.

Comment: What was the error message?  (Incidentally, it runs fine here: http://ideone.com/himWvk).

Comment: I'm unable to see the "Java Application" in "Run As" menu.

Comment: set your class public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hussain is right about making your class public but I thought I'd add some additional information for posterity.

- As your code now stands, you are not running your code in another thread.  You can remove the `extends Thread` from your code and it will still work fine.  Your `main` is just calling the `run()` method directly and not invoking any of the thread magic.
- If you do want your code to run in another thread then you will need to add `a.start();` to start the thread running and `a.join();` to wait for it to finish.  In the `start()` method, the thread is forked and the `run()` method is invoked.

  ```
  A a = new A();
  // start the thread which calls run()
  a.start();
  // wait for the thread to finish
  a.join();
  System.out.println(a.i);
  ```
- Lastly, it is recommended that you `implements Runnable` and do as opposed to `extends Thread`.   So your code would look like:

  ```
  A a = new A();
  Thread thread = new Thread(a);
  // start the thread which calls run()
  thread.start();
  // wait for the thread to finish
  thread.join();
  System.out.println(a.i);
  ```
- If you have not done so before, I'd recommend reading a [tutorial on threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: Well explained. Thanks Gray.

Answer (score 2):

all you have to do is to set your class public

```
public class A extends Thread {
    private int i;
    public void run(){i=1;}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(); a.run();System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}
```